# difference between if ( !statement) and if (statement != true)?

Tags: java, android

I had some case in which first seemed to change the value of Boolean and second didn't! Is there a real difference between the two:

```
boolean x = true;

if (x != true) {}
if (!x) {}
```

Comment: no difference, but the second one is more elegant

Comment: In addition to all of the answers, the Java compiler will optimize this down when it hits bytecode.  Both will be a single IFNE.

Comment: To me, the difference is that `if (x != true)` looks like it was written by someone who didn't properly understand booleans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Although the second idiom is deemed more elegant (less cumbersome and verbose) by some.

**There's a catch!**

The `!=` operator is used for object reference equality, so in an edge case scenario with wrapper `Boolean`s instead of primitives...

```
Boolean b0 = new Boolean("true"); // value true
Boolean b1 = new Boolean("true"); // value true as well
System.out.println(!b0); // prints false
System.out.println(!b1); // prints false too
System.out.println(b0 != b1); // references not equal, prints true!
```

**Output**

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between both sentences. `x != true` is equal to `!x`

If you compare a boolean variable with *equal* comparator, you can introduce a mistake. Examples:

```
if (x == false) {} // executes the "if" body when "x" is false

if (!x) {} // same of previous example, executes the "if" body when "x" is false

if (x = false) {} // assign the "false" value to x, and never executes the "if" body
```

The last example use a single "=" character, and assign a value. The first example use two "=" characters, and compare both values without assign anything.

Answer (score 0):

In java `!=` stand for not equal, `!` for not so:

```
 x != ture // X not equal true (x = false)

 !x // Not x (x = true, not x = false)
```

So they are equal.